# How I can upgrade PHP 5.1.6 to 5.2 or higher on FreeBSD 6.2?

Tags: php, upgrade, freebsd

I have Internal error message and pyrocms require PHP 5.2 up.
How I can upgrade PHP version by do not install new web server?

### My server:

ns1# php -v

PHP 5.1.6 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2008 21:35:05)
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies

ns1# uname -r

6.2-RELEASE
ns1#

Comment: duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/105876/how-do-i-update-php-and-all-its-modules-on-freebsd-in-one-go

Comment: Thank you for quickly reply and sorry for duplicate question.
It possible to upgrade on FreeBSD 6.2 by and not effect to the web system?

Comment: thanks google, thats how i found that

Comment: I know many problem can found by google but I don't know that is real correction. Thank again for your answer.

Comment: The reason why I asked the question because I think "What happen if I run one command, when I enter and then try install new web server by 3-4 hour."

Comment: Generally, questions that involve "what happens if I enter X command and then the server goes down for a while?" are [SF] questions, not SO questions.

Comment: 1. Take a snapshot of the server. 2. Try it. 3. Observe results. 4. Act accordingly.

Comment: Upgrade your web server to a supported release of FreeBSD. [6.2-RELEASE was end-of-lifed on May 31st, 2008](https://www.freebsd.org/security/unsupported.html), and no longer receives updates, security or otherwise.

Comment: OK not problem if you mean questions when server fault but I mean how to go without something wrong. sorry for question.

Comment: The [FreeBSD ports tree](https://www.freebsd.org/ports/) at the time of posting this comment install PHP 5.4 by default but also contains 5.5 and 5.6. So update your server to (preferably) [FreeBSD 10.1](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.1R/announce.html) and install a recent PHP from ports.

Comment: Thank you for many answer, now I just change to Ubuntu.